# Evaluating: $\int^{n}_{1}[\ln(x) - \ln(\lfloor x \rfloor)] dx $

Tags: integration, logarithms

I am attempting to evaluate the integral:

$$\int^{n}_{1}\ln(x) - \ln(\lfloor x \rfloor) dx $$

To a form:

$$f(x) + O(g(x))$$

where $g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty $

How do I compute that f(x) or atleast some type of series representation for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have:
$$
\int_1^n \ln(x) \,dx = \Big.\left(x\ln(x) - x\right)\Big|_1^n = n \ln(n) - n + 1
$$

And:
\begin{align}
\int_1^n \ln(\lfloor x \rfloor) \,dx &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_i^{i+1} \ln(\lfloor x \rfloor) \,dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_i^{i+1} \ln(i) \,dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \ln(i) \\
&= \ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}i\right) \\
&= \ln\left((n-1)!\right)
\end{align}

Thus, your integral is equal to:
$$
n \ln(n) - n + 1 - \ln\left((n-1)!\right)
$$